# Can you factor a second order polynomial with negative leading coefficient with only two factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ with $a\in \left(-\infty, 0\right)$ and $b, c\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$. Is it possible to find $p, q, r, s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\left(px + q\right)\left(rx + s\right) = ax^2 + bx + c$? And if not, why not? I was trying to factor $-y^2 + y - h$, with $h>0$ and I couldn't find any way to factor this into only two factors. I welcome answers involving abstract algebra if that is relevant to this question.

Comment: Factor the minus out then complete the square?

Comment: But that will technically be three factors. I am interested in why it is impossible (or possible) to do so without factoring out (-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the sign of $a \ne 0$, the roots are $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Hence we have

\begin{align}ax^2+bx+c &= a\left(x- \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right) \left(x- \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right) \\&= \left(ax- \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}\right) \left(x- \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\end{align}

Note that it is possible that $b^2-4ac$ to be negative though.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the obvious solution to put (-1) back into the factorization.